# Integrate Angular2 into existing JSF project

Tags: jsf, typescript, angular

I'm looking into a new frontend framework for our company's JSF portal and am considering Angular2. I want to gradually migrate specific components on the page from JSF to Angular2 / REST. I don't want to use Angular2 for routing, at least not yet, and I don't want Angular to completely take over the page: some components will still need to be JSF for the foreseeable future.

Ideally, I'd wrap the content of the body of my JSF template with my Angular root component and project the HTML rendered by JSF into the root component, so that the JSF works as before and any Angular components within the template are picked up and can all communicate. E.g.:

```
<h:body>
  <my-app>
    <h:panelGroup styleClass="languageSwitcher">
      <h:form>
        <h:selectOneMenu value="#{languageHandler.language}" onchange="submit()">
          <f:selectItem itemValue="en" itemLabel="English" />
          <f:selectItem itemValue="nl" itemLabel="Dutch" />
        </h:selectOneMenu>
      </h:form>
    </h:panelGroup>

    <my-angular-component data-source="/rest/mydata"></my-angular-component>
  </my-app>
<h:body>
```

With Angular 1, I'd use transclusion to make this work. However, as I understand it, [Angular 2 content projection does not work on the root component](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/1858), as the rendered HTML is not considered an Angular-compiled view.

I also considered using the root component's `templateURL` to get the JSF rendered page dynamically, but this is difficult to implement and doesn't play well with the numerous POST's that JSF does.

The only way I can think to make this work is to make a root component of each Angular component that replaces a bit of JSF, and on every page bootstrap all components I use. The drawback here is that I need a lot of boilerplate code to bootstrap every Angular component I build, and they don't have a shared root component so communication between them is limited. Furthermore, I'll need to configure each Angular component through attributes, but as these [aren't picked up automatically either](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/1858) I'll need to add custom code to each component to pick them up:

```
class MyAngularComponent {
  constructor(public elementRef: ElementRef) {
    this.dataSourceUrl = this.elementRef.nativeElement.getAttribute("data-source");
  }
}
```

Then when I finally replace the entire frontend with Angular, I have to refactor each component again to use `@Input` in stead of retrieving information from attributes manually.

Does anybody know a better way to do this? Or do JSF and Angular2 simply not mix well?

Comment: *"Or do JSF and Angular2 simply not mix well?"* If that were true, http://angularfaces.com would never have existed.

Comment: AFAIK angularfaces uses AngularJS (aka Angular 1), which supports transclusion, greatly simplifying the process.

Comment: If Angular 1 will fit your needs, why are you using 2?

Comment: I didn't say Angular 1 fits my needs. It supports transclusion which helps, but it has other drawbacks as we found out during our last project.

Comment: @RomkevanderMeulen What did you guys settle finally, we are in the same  state .

Comment: We finally decided to use Aurelia in stead of Angular. Among other things, it supports this scenario far better than Angular does.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you can't make a full page the unit of rewrite, you will have to split the page in sections and migrate them one section at a time.

Just take a section of the page, create a JSF component and make it a fully bootstrapped angular 2 app, by reusing the HTML and CSS only.

If you need to integrate this into the JSF lifecycle instead of calling REST web services, you need to inject the data produced by the angular 2 in a hidden field of a JSF form. Place the data in JSON format and deserialize it on the server using Jackson.

Its likely all not worth it, compared to rewriting the app one page at a time using angular 2 and rest controllers.

You can configure the server to redirect certain pages to serve static files which are Angular 2 pages,  while the rest remains under JSF.

Answer (score 0):

Make a wrapper Component for your application at the root level, After that you can slowly start chipping away at the your code to convert your pieces into components that you can place along side your other HTML.

Yes, you have to go through to refactoring of @inputs but you don't need to do everything at the same time, Start one Component at a time, Just enable the Angular 2 Component at root by adding a simple wrapper to facilitate component building which works around your Compiled HTML issue.

**My advice for your team is to start with making a separate project clean and small and migrate one feature at a time to the new project. You will have a better developer experience and scoping instead of a messy in place rewrite.**

Comment: We've explicitly decided against starting from scratch for this project, so that's not an option.

I'm not sure what you mean by a wrapper component at the root level. You mean like `<my-app>` in my first example? Because that won't work, which is the whole problem.